# How to refresh a region after rows returned condition?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page in my apex application version 5, where I'm using a basic search using text fields, a button search and a classic report when I'm getting information for that search ..here is the thing..
For that search I want to display 2 list values only if I get information in the classic report below.
If I use server condition when rows returned I need to refresh my page manually to display those list values, do you know how can I display those after search information? automatically.

Comment: how does your search button work?typically, if you have a search button and its action is submit, the page will load automatically; there you dont have to refresh the page manually to trigger the condition.

Comment: Hi, with a dynamic action, for items to submit (text fields) executing a PLSQL null code, then another dynamic action refreshing region

Comment: you dont have to submit the items if you change the action of the button to submit page since it will submit the whole page and will refresh automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use client side conditions type javascript to check if the report has rows, this JS code may helps you

```
var tableSize = $('#myReport tbody tr').length>0
```

and then in the true action you display your lists.